# ¿Cómo agrupar valores de acuerdo a rangos predeterminados?

Tags: r

Mi consulta:
Tengo la siguiente tabla con  una variable independiente “Datos” y una dependiente “Resultados”

```
Datos   Resultado
28  -2
28  -2
28  5
28  -2
28  -2
28  -2
28  -2
28  5
28  -2
28  5
28  -2
28  -2
28  -2
28  -2
28  -2
28  -2
28  -2
27  5
27  5
27  -2
27  5
27  5
27  5
27  5
27  5
27  -2
27  -2
27  -2
27  5
27  5
27  5
27  -2
26  5
26  -2
26  5
26  -2
26  -2
26  5
26  -2
25  -2
25  -2
25  -2
25  5
25  -2
25  5
24  -2
24  -2
24  -2
24  5
24  5
24  -2
24  5
24  5
23  -2
23  5
23  -2
23  -2
23  -2
23  -2
23  -2
23  -2
23  -2
22  -2
22  -2
22  5
22  -2
22  -2
22  -2
22  -2
22  -2
22  -2
22  -2
22  -2
```

De acuerdo a esa tabla, cuando “Datos” es >27, la suma de “Resultados” es -13. Para valores de “Datos” =<24 la suma de “Resultados” es -26. Con valores de “Datos” >=24 y <=27 la suma de resultados es 61, que es el resultado máximo que se puede lograr con la serie anterior.
Mi consulta es: ¿existe alguna librería en R que me permita realizar este análisis?, o sea, encontrar el rango de valores independientes que me permitan maximizar los resultados ligados a ellos

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de los datos que has mencionado:

```
df <- structure(list(Datos = c(28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L
), Resultado = c(-2L, -2L, 5L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, 5L, -2L, 5L, 
-2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, 5L, 5L, -2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, -2L, -2L, -2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, -2L, 5L, -2L, 5L, -2L, -2L, 5L, 
-2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, 5L, -2L, 5L, -2L, -2L, -2L, 5L, 5L, -2L, 
5L, 5L, -2L, 5L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, 
5L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L)), .Names = c("Datos", 
"Resultado"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -73L))
```

No es necesario ninguna librería externa, con la funcionalidad base puedes resolverlo de forma mas o menos sencilla:

```
sum(df[which(df$Datos > 27),2])
sum(df[which(df$Datos <= 27 & df$Datos >= 24),2])
sum(df[which(df$Datos < 24),2])

[1] -13
[1] 61
[1] -26
```

- Con `df$Datos > 27` obtienes un vector lógico de los valores que cumplen dicha condición.
- Usando [`which()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.html) obtenemos las posiciones de los valores `TRUE` de la condición anterior
- y usando `[ ... ,2]` filtramos justamente los valores que cumplen la condición y nos quedamos solo con la columna de `Resultados`
- Por último, aplicamos el [`sum()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html) para sumar dichos valores

Otra forma un poco más directa es usar [`findInterval()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html) que separa en grupos los valores que se corresponden a intervalos previamente definidos. A modo de ejemplo, comparamos el vector `c(23,27,28)` con 3 intervalos definidos según los límites `c(24,27)`

```
findInterval(c(23,27,28), c(24,27), rightmost.closed=T)
```

Por defecto los intervalos son inclusivos a izquierda y exclusivos a derecha, por lo que si queremos que uno de ellos se 24 <= *intervalo* >= 27, podremos usar el parámetro `rightmost.closed=T`.

El resultado será: `[1] 0 1 2`, el 23 corresponderá al intervalo 0, el 27 al intervalo 1 y el 28 al 2. Definiendo de esta forma el intervalo a cada valor lo único que restaría es agrupar los mismos con [`aggregate()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) y aplicar la suma:

```
aggregate(Resultado ~ findInterval(df$Datos, c(24,27), rightmost.closed=T), df, sum)[,2]
[1] -26  61 -13
```

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa usando funciones de la librería `tidyverse`.

> Uso el data.frame que creó @Patricio Moracho

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  #Creo una variable explícita ad hoc con los grupos. 
  # No es elegante, pero sirve para validar el paso intermedio.
  mutate(intervalo = case_when(Datos > 27 ~ "mayor27",
                              between(Datos, 24, 27) ~ "24-27", 
                              Datos < 24 ~ "menor24")) %>% 
  #Agrupo por las categorías de intervalo
  group_by(intervalo) %>% 
  #Sumo Resultado dentro de cada grupo
  summarise(sum(Resultado))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
intervalo `sum(Resultado)`
<chr>                <int>
1 24-27                   61
2 mayor27                -13
3 menor24                -26
```

El resultado es en sí mismo un data.frame, listo para traficar o presentar en una tabla formateada.

## Paso a paso

`mutate()` se usa para crear una columna. Esa columna se define con el nombre `intervalo` y es el output de la función `case_when()`.

`case_when()` define unas condiciones lógicas o aritméticas del lado izquierdo de `~` y a la derecha se asigna el valor cuando se cumple la condición.

`between()` es una función de conveniencia de `dplyr` para definir un intervalo. Es sólo para facilitar la escritura.

`group_by` agrupa los datos, lo que siga se aplicará **a cada grupo**

`summarise()` aplica una función a cada grupo, en este caso la sumatoria de `Resultado` con `sum(Resultado)`

La sintaxis de `tidyverse` (en este caso `dplyr` que está dentro de `tidyverse`) tiene convenciones diferentes a las de R base. La uso bastante porque hace explícitos los pasos intermedios y eso ayuda a validar los resultados. Podemos ejecutar cada línea antes del símbolo `%>%` e ir viendo si cada paso es correcto.

La desventaja es que tenemos que importar una librería muy grande para hacer operaciones sencillas que podrías hacerse con R base, sin librerías adicionales, como lo demuestra la respuesta de @pmoracho

Comment: Creo que en ambas respuestas están trabajando con tablas donde ya se conocen los rangos de valores y sus respectivos resultados. Lo que busco es librería que me ayude a buscar en tablas donde  no se conocen los rangos de valores. O sea, buscar en cualquier tabla en la que tenga valores independientes y resultados asociados a cada uno de ellos, encontrar los rangos de valores independientes para el (o los) que sea mayor la sumatoria de resultados.

Comment: Hugo, no logro entender lo que necesitas. ¿Podrías reformular tu pregunta con más detalles? Serviría que aclares que información tienes a priori, que información NO tienes a priori y quieres obtener y con qué criterios la obtendrías. Gracias! *PD: si encontraste una solución por favor publícala.*

Comment: Ya lo solucioné. Gracias